# Join Leave action logs not working for some reason, someone?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have these join / leave audit logs that also send a welcome message in a channel and give people a role when they join the server. I am using discord.js version 12.3.1 and node version 14.0.0 because they work the best for me. Here is my code with some commented out stuff to show you what stuff does.

```js
//Member Joined
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    if (!member.guild.id === '720659736990842880') return; //make sure it is only tracking the right server.
    if (member.user.bot) return member.roles.add('797211417031213116'); // give bots the bot role and do nothing else

    member.send("Welcome to the **NGM Boys Club**!\nI am Next Gen Men (the bot), the server's very own custom discord bot. If you have any questions, please DM me and I will forward your message to our team. *(Also don't forget to grab roles in <#764153697566720051> when you get verified!)*"); //DM the user when they join the server
    member.roles.add('789252052516864081') //give members the onboarding role
    member.roles.add('811345066681172038') //give members the restricted role

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() //start of the embed for the join action log
    const target = member.user
    embed.setColor('');
    embed.setDescription(`Member Joined: <@${member.id}>\n __**Account Created**__: ` + member.user.createdAt);
    embed.setAuthor(`${member.user.tag} joined the server`, member.user.avatarURL);
    embed.setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL());
    embed.setFooter('User ID:' + member.id);

    await bot.channels.cache.get('811344556205277214').send(`** Welcome to the club, <@${member.id}>!\nThere are a few steps before you can get added to the rest of the server. Tag \`\`@Facilitators\`\` if you have any questions or would like to find out more about the community.\n> 1. Start by filling out the application form: http://nextgenmen.ca/club/apply\n> 2. After we’ve received it, one of the facilitators will ping you to verify your identity on the voice channel\n> 3. Once you’ve been verified, you’ll get added to the rest of the server`);
    const msg = await bot.channels.cache.get('789257779076268102').send(embed); //send a message to a channel when they join the server (this is the public one)
});

//Member Left
bot.on('guildMemberRemove', async member => {
    if (!member.guild.id === '720659736990842880') return;
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed() //start of the leaving action log
    const roles = member.roles.cache.filter(role => role.id !== member.guild.id).map(role => role.toString())

    embed.setColor('');
    embed.setDescription(`Member Left: <@${member.id}>\n __**Roles:**__ \n${roles.join(`\n`)}`);
    embed.setAuthor(`${member.user.tag} left the server`, member.user.avatarURL);
    embed.setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL());
    embed.setFooter('User ID:' + member.id);

    const msg = await bot.channels.cache.get('789257779076268102').send(embed) //send the action log to the correct channel
});
```

The problem is that it just won't work and it isn't giving me any errors what so ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep in mind that for `guildMember...` events, you need to have the bot invited with this on:
[image: Server members intent]
It can be found at the bottom of the "bot" section of your application.